# How to modify three command (regular expressions) in one line to use in sed (instead of fnr.exe)

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I'm using fnr.exe (https://findandreplace.codeplex.com).

My homework:

```
Value: String
Details: other_str
Number: xxx
Value: String
Details: other_str
Number: xxx
Value: String
Details: other_str
Number: xxx
Value: String
Details: other_str
Number: xxx
```

after using fnr.exe i have

```
 String
 xxx
 String
 xxx
 String
 xxx
 String
 xxx
```

Really good tool for find and replace in place a lot of files using ie. regex.

I tried today compare speed of this tool with sed in Cygwin.

Unfortunately my command not working in seed.
Don't know why. Can You help me?

For now in fnr.exe I'm using this command via terminal (and works well):

```
"C:\Test\soft\fnr.exe" --cl --dir "C:\Test" --fileMask "*.*" --caseSensitive --useRegEx --find "^(Value: )|^.*(Details).*$\s|^(Number.*: )" --replace ""
```

Then I tried with sed

```
sed -i 's/^(Value: )|^.*(Details).*$\s|^(Number.*: )/\1/' *.*
```

and not working...

---

:) :)
OK I FOUND A SOLUTION FOR THIS PROBLEM

HERE IS THE CODE FOR ALL FILES IN FOLDER:

```
sed -i -e '/Details/d' -e 's/Value: //g' -e 's/Number: //g' *.txt
```

Explanation - we want to remove second line and two strings "Value" and "Number" and save it in place in all text files or for one file ie. (example.txt instead of *.txt)

Remove second line

```
sed -i -e '/Details/d'
```

Remove string "Value"

```
-e 's/Value: //g'
```

Remove string "Number"

```
-e 's/Number: //g'
```

Speed between FNR.EXE and SED is tremendous!

> Example.txt (few milions records)
>
> FNR.EXE - 3 min
>
> SED - 36 seconds :) :)

I wonder if awk or grep would be faster than sed?

Cheers!

Comment: Use `-E` option. But `^.*(Details).*$\s` will never match, you may want to remove `\s` since there can't be any text after string end. `sed -i -E ...`. And if you need to keep all the captures you need to replace with `/\1\2\3/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why `^.*(Details).*$\s` will never match if it is a regex and works well?

Comment: Where does it work well? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NFeYTX/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew dn't know why, in fnr.exe works great!

Comment: How does it work? What is the input text like? What is the expected result?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I found a solution :)

Comment: Now, that you shared it, it is really clear what you wanted. Why didn't you just explain that before?  Asking a question keeping all details in secret does not help. You still may use `sed -i -E '/Details/d;s/(Value|Number): //g' *.txt`. Grep won't help here.

Comment: As for `awk`, try `awk '!/Details/{gsub(/(Value|Number): /, "", $0); print}' *.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Grep won't help here since you need to remove parts of lines.

You may use a POSIX ERE regex (enabled with `-E` option) with `sed` like

```
sed -i -E '/Details/d;s/(Value|Number): //g' *.txt
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/uKZboB).

However, `awk` is usually recommended:

```
awk '!/Details/{gsub(/(Value|Number): /, ""); print}' *.txt
```

See the [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/9luLA1)

**Details**

- `!/Details/` - if a line does not contain `Details`
- `gsub(/(Value|Number): /, "")` (note the input for `gsub` is the whole line as the input variable is omitted) - remove `Value:` and `Number:` with a space after them and
- `print` - print the modified line (`$0`).